# Random forests visual introduction-level reference or tutorial

Tags: references, random-forest, cart, teaching

I have seen several references, but am looking for something easy to follow that illustrates Random Forests in regression and feature importance applications.

I want to make sure that I explain this at the 101 level. Something like [this](http://edchedch.wordpress.com/tag/ensemble-methods/), but more pictorial like this [pdf](http://www.whrc.org/education/indonesia/pdf/DecisionTrees_RandomForest_v2.pdf).

I am having a hard time getting across a concrete high-level example of how predictors are being chosen and making them tangable to a general audience.

Answer (score 1):

"A Gentle Introduction to Random Forests, Ensembles, and Performance Metrics in a Commercial System", http://citizennet.com/blog/2012/11/10/random-forests-ensembles-and-performance-metrics/

"Machine Learning" [Utube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kYujfDgmNk